# Ubuntu cups-pdf print from windows 10 output file not in /home/xxx/PDF but it's in /var/spool/cups-pdf/ANONYMOUS/

Tags: 18.04, printing, pdf, cups-lpd

I print `.docx` from Windows 10 to `cups-pdf` printer on Ubuntu. After printed, pdf file output is not in `/home/xxx/PDF_folder` but it's in `/var/spool/cups-pdf/ANONYMOUS/`.

If I print on Ubuntu same computer then it show pdf output in `/home/xxx/PDF` folder.

How to fix it?

Comment: *If I print on Ubuntu same computer then it show pdf output in /home/xxx/PDF folder.* What is different from precedent way? Another software, everything done on Ubuntu (when the 1rst is done on Windows and trying to store inside Ubuntu partition), ... ?

Comment: I wonder all pdf file will show in /home/xxx/PDF folder. If it show in separate folder it have no problem. I'm new for cups. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that the print jobs from Windows are anonymous, so they won't go into your `/home/xxx/PDF` folder. If you look in `/etc/cups/cups-pdf.conf`, you should find the `AnonDirName` setting that configures where to put files for anonymous jobs. By default, it's `/var/spool/cups-pdf/ANONYMOUS`.